# codeigniter index.php file mod rewrite

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am new to codeigniter and using this as my url

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/site
```

and have included following htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase/codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

after including this htaccess filr to codeigniter folder the web page stops working on both

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/site
```

and

```
http://localhost/codeigniter
```

basically i need

```
http://localhost/codeigniter
```

to work

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a whitespace between your RewriteBase and the base URI:

```
RewriteBase /codeigniter
```

This is probably why things has stopped working (a server error status 500, which you could find in your error log).

Comment: oh yes its working thanks.!!! can you tell me how can i get this http://localhost/codeigniter/
to http://localhost/codeigniter/site automatically

Comment: Either move your whole application into a subfolder named `site` under the `codeigniter` folder and change your mod rewrite rules to match.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For more details [Click Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: This will force his requests to be sent to http://localhost/ instead - not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your codeigniter site default to the site controller you need to update config/routes.php to set the site controller as the default route.

For the rewrite issue see @Repox's answer.